# Regex for 9-digit phone number dot-separated

Tags: regex

I would like to check if a phone number contains exactly 3 digits - dot - 3 digits - dot - 3 digits. (e.g. `123.456.789`)

So far I have this, but it doesn't work:

```
^(\d{3}\){2}\d{4}$
```

Comment: It should be `^(\d{3}\.){2}\d{3}$`

Comment: wow! thanks, can't believe this took me so long...

Answer (score 1):

Note that an escaped bracket `\)` loses its special meaning in regex and the pattern becomes invalid since the capturing group is not closed.

If you want to match a dot with a regex, you need to include it to your pattern, and if you say 3 digits must be at the end there is no point in declaring 4 digits with `\d{4}`.

```
^(\d{3}\.){2}\d{3}$
        ^       ^
```

or if we expand the first group:

```
^\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}$
```

So all the fix consists in adding a dot after the second backslash and adjusting the final limiting quantifier.

Note that for mostly "stylistics" concerns (since efficiency gain is insignificant) I'd use a non-capturing group with the first regex variant:

```
^(?:\d{3}\.){2}\d{3}$
```